# Getting a unique ID per tab page for a facebook app

Tags: facebook

Working on developing a facebook app that will primarily be used within the context of a tab page.  For each person adding this app there should be a unique view of data that is shown specifically for their tab page.  Is there a way to get a unique identifier per installation to key that off of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it's possible. Facebook will send the page id in the `signed_request` (sounds unique enough? ;-) ):

> When a user navigates to the Facebook
>   Page, they will see your Page Tab
>   added in the next available tab
>   position. Broadly, a Page Tab is
>   loaded in exactly the same way as a
>   Canvas Page. When a user selects your
>   Page Tab, you will received the
>   `signed_request` parameter with one
>   additional parameter, `page`. This
>   parameter contains a JSON object with
>   an id (the page id of the current
>   page), `admin` (if the user is a admin
>   of the page), and `liked` (if the user
>   has liked the page). As with a Canvas
>   Page, you will not receive all the
>   user information accessible to your
>   app in the `signed_request` until the
>   user authorizes your app.

[Source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/).