# How to find fanpage name/id from tab app

Tags: facebook, tabs

I have a FB app embedded on a a fanpage tab.  When my app is called I can get the information in the signed request.  But I need some more information so I can store and access data locally indexed by the particular fanpage and app.

How can I determine the name and id of the fanpage tab the app is embedded on (as opposed to the fanpage id which is in the signed_request)?

I know the app id is in the parent url but I don't think I can access the parent url from the child iframe for security reasons.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting a unique ID per tab page for a facebook app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302471/getting-a-unique-id-per-tab-page-for-a-facebook-app)

Answer (score 0):

Like the page then go [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) and click on the 'likes' like about 1/3 of the way down. That will show you your likes, which will contain that page and its id